# cordova file-transfer plugin - file:///storage/emulated/0/Foldername/myImage.jpg is working in xperia z ultra but not in oneplus 2

Tags: android, cordova, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova

I am developing a cordova application using visual studio 2017 to download images. I have added the cordova-plugin-file and cordova-plugin-file-transfer plugins. I used the following code.

```
function downloadFile() {
var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
var downloadurl = document.getElementById("bigprofile").src;
var uri = encodeURI(downloadurl);


var fileURL = "file:///storage/sdcard0/Foldername/myimage.jpg";


fileTransfer.download(
    uri, fileURL, function (entry) {
        alert("download complete: " + entry.toURL());
    },

    function (error) {
        alert("download error source " + error.source);
        alert("download error target " + error.target);
        alert("download error code" + error.code);
    },

    false, {
        headers: {
            "Authorization": "Basic dGVzdHVzZXJuYW1lOnRlc3RwYXNzd29yZA=="
        }
    }
);
}
```

This method works fine in xperia z ultra. But it's not working with my oneplus 2 device.

The following path too didn't work.

```
var fileURL = "file:///storage/emulated/0/Foldername/myimage.jpg";
```

Later i tried

```
var fileURL = "cdvfile://localhost/persistent/myimage.jpg";
```

This was successful. I got an alert

```
"download complete:file///data/user/0/io.cordova.myappeb072d/files/files/myimage.jpg".
```

I used ES explorer to view this path. But there is no such path. In the root there is a data folder but it is empty.

Please suggest me a method to download a file, that is common across all other android platforms irrespective of the devices